# Appropriate webpack loader missing error when using bcrypt in Node with TypeScript server

Tags: typescript, webpack, bcrypt, angular-universal

I'm trying to use **Angular Universal** and **Typescript** in my development environment. When I attempt to run *server-side rendering* (SSR):

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

I get an error saying that an *appropriate loader is missing* certain file types. But the issue only seems to happen when I use bcrypt:

[image: screenshot]

**Example Error #1**:

```
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>
```

**Example Error #2:**

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // This script needs to be compatible with PowerShell v2 to run on Windows 2008R2 and Windows 7.
| 
> using System;
| using System.Text;
| using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Like I said, both happen every time I use bcrypt. For example:

```
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds);
```

### What Have You Tried?

I tried to changing my `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.common.config.js`.

**webpack.config.dev.js**:

I added the 2nd loader (just following npm web-site instructions):

```
loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel']
            }
            { 
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'html-loader' 
            },
        ]
```

**webpack.common.config.js:**

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.html', '.cs']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
            {
        test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|tiff)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'sharp-loader',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: {
            // Preset 1
            thumbnail: {
              format: ['webp', 'jpeg'],
              width: 200,
              quality: 60,
            },
            // Preset 2
            prefetch: {
              // Format-specific options can be specified like this:
              format: {id: 'jpeg', quality: 30},
              mode: 'cover',
              blur: 100,
              inline: true,
              size: 50,
            },
          },
        },
      }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Did you configure the `angular.json` to use the webpack builder instead of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`? Are you using ASP.NET Core as backend?

Comment: @Pieterjan well I ended up using different package "bcrypt-ts" and it works perfectly